# In Python the Apache Arrow ADBC driver causing silent program exit on connection attempt to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, pyarrow

My config:

- Windows
- `python=3.11.7`
- `pandas=2.2.0`
- `adbc-driver-manager=0.9.0`
- `adbc-driver-postgresql=0.9.0`
- `pyarrow=15.0.0`

---

Trying to implement the newish `ADBC Driver` from Apache Arrow with the connection to my PostgreSQL database. Code is simple enough, but when trying to establish the connection the program exits silently with no exceptions raised.

```py
import adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi
import pandas as pd

uri = (
    'postgresql://' +
    f'{config["USERNAME"]}:' +
    f'{config["PASSWORD"]}@' +
    f'{config["HOST"]}:' +
    '5432/' +
    f'{config["DB_NAME"]}'
)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

with adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi.connect(uri) as conn:  # program exits silently here
   # neither of these lines run
   print('connection made, going to upload now')
   df.to_sql("pandas_table", conn, index=False)

print('made it pass connection and upload')  # doesn't run
```

---

**Debugging done**

- Validated database can be connected to with:

```py
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

uri = (
    'postgresql://' +
    f'{config["USERNAME"]}:' +
    f'{config["PASSWORD"]}@' +
    f'{config["HOST"]}:' +
    '5432/' +
    f'{config["DB_NAME"]}'
)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(uri)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    df.to_sql("pandas_table", conn, index=False)
```

- Ensured necessary packages installed:

  - `pandas=2.2.0`
  - `adbc-driver-manager=0.9.0`
  - `adbc-driver-postgresql=0.9.0`
  - `pyarrow=15.0.0`

Comment: Are you sure about that PyArrow version? The minimum PyArrow is 8.0.0. How were the packages installed?

Additionally, is it possible to provide the data so we can try and replicate?

Comment: It may be better to file an issue on the repository for discussion.

Comment: @li.davidm thanks for catching that. I updated to the correct version of 15.0.0. I understand asking for the data, but it really doesn't have any bearing. The single line `with adbc_driver_postgresql.dbapi.connect(uri) as conn` is failing without the data ever factoring in.